# How to use SetState or function with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-state-management

this is my code from a  React Project with firebase , I am stuck from the Morning in this Problem please help me plzzz

```
constructor (){
        super()
        this.state = {Message : false}
        this.Navigate = this.Navigate.bind(this)


        CompLoad = true

        var i = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

        firebase.database().ref('users/' + i + '/inbox').limitToLast(1)

         .on('value' , function (x){

            if (CompLoad === false){

            var data = x.val()  

            alert(JSON.stringify(data))

            R = 'Inbox'

            this.Navigate()

            }

            if (CompLoad === true){
                CompLoad = false
            }


            })

            }
```

it gives me error :-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Navigate' of null
```

Navigate function

```
Navigate =  () => {     
        this.context.router.history.push('/' + R)
    }
```

if i replace Navigate with setState

```
this.setState({
                Message : true
            })
```

react says :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback function is changing the context of `this` and its no longer the `class`.
Either use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get a lexical context:

```
 .on('value' , (x) => {
....
```

Or temporarily hold the `this` value above the callback and use it:

```
// outside the callback in the constructor
const that = this;
// inside the callback
 .on('value' , function (x){
that.Navigate()
```

Answer (score 1):

this isn’t accessible unitl and unless you bind it or use arrow function.

Change it to arrow function

```
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + i + '/inbox').limitToLast(1)

     .on('value' , (x) => {

        if (CompLoad === false){

        var data = x.val()  

        alert(JSON.stringify(data))

        R = 'Inbox'

        this.Navigate()

        }

        if (CompLoad === true){
            CompLoad = false
        }


        })

        }
```

Or bind it like

```
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + i + '/inbox').limitToLast(1)

     .on('value' , function (x){

        if (CompLoad === false){

        var data = x.val()  

        alert(JSON.stringify(data))

        R = 'Inbox'

        this.Navigate()

        }

        if (CompLoad === true){
            CompLoad = false
        }


        }.bind(this));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this callback to use lexcial scope

```
.on('value' , function (x){
...
```

to

```
.on('value' , (x) => {
...
```

see more on [lexical scoping](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should assign the property not variable inside the constructor:

Example:

```
CompLoad = true // incorrect
this.CompLoad = true // correct
```

Secondly, you should not use `setState` inside the constructor.

Thirdly, to access parent context `this` inside your function, you may use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

And finally, what you want to perform an api action and set the state, then, you should use `componentDidMount` [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and call api from there and update the state as necessary.